# How to include a C system header instead of a C++ system header of the same name in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, macos, include, g++, complex-numbers

My Mac OS X system seems to have several different versions of the header file `complex.h`, and they are incompatible.

- `/usr/include/complex.h` defines the C99 implementation of `_Complex` numbers,
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/complex.h` is a thin wrapper around the C++ header without the `.h`, that defines the C++ implementation of `std::complex` numbers.

My problem is that I have a C library compiled using C99 complex numbers, and I need to link my C++ program against it. However, its include file references `<complex.h>`, and when compiling my program, g++ picks up the C++ backwards-compatibility header instead, and all hell breaks loose.

I've tried passing a `-I/usr/include` flag to g++, but it didn't help.

How do I force g++ to use the C header instead of the C++ one when including `<complex.h>`?

Comment: Best not to. Compile the C library with C, and link the result.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I have compiled the C library with C. But I need to include its header files to link against it, don't I? That's where the problem is coming in.

Comment: Hmm, I might be able to just copy over the prototypes for the functions I need, and that might work for now. (But if later I need some of the library functions which require complex numbers, I'll have this problem again.)

Comment: Keep the interface as clean as possible. If you only need complex numbers internally, there's no need to expose anything. If you need to have complex numbers in the public interface, you have come up with something suitable. I'm not sure if C++11 includes the `_Complex` native type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I should come back and accept an answer.

The top comment basically says "Just don't do it". I ended up not doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an entirely optimal solution, but if you simply want to ensure that you get the desired version of the header without modifying the code, you could try using a combination of the `-nostdinc` and `-nostdinc++`  with a `-I/usr/include` flag. If I understand the documentation correctly, that should prevent gcc from looking at the standard list of system header files and instead defer to those supplied with the `-I` flag. That should override Os X's decision to automatically include the backward compatibility directory on the header search list.

There is the possibility however, that with those options you will be unable to compile. GCC has provisions for the case where you supply a directory with the `-I` flag that are already present on the default system header search list (it will ignore the extraneous `-I` flag). Hopefully it is smart enough to notice that the system search list has been cleared (by the `-nostdinc` flags), allowing it to property add `-I/usr/include`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of the functions from the C library that are used by the C++ code have `_Complex` parameters or return types, you can modify the C header file by surrounding the `#include <complex.h>` directive, as well as anything else in the header that uses `_Complex`, with `#ifndef __cplusplus` / `#endif` directives so that the C++ code won't see it and be confused by it.  On the other hand, if you absolutely can't modify the C header, you can copy the function prototypes and anything else used by the C++ code into a new header that is included by the C++ code.

**EDIT**

If you really have your heart set on just disambiguating the headers, you can try `#include "/usr/include/complex.h"` instead of simply `#include <complex.h>`, but using an absolute path to a standard library header like this isn't good practice and probably isn't portable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the headers in your code with an extern block, I.e

```
  extern "C"{
  // include your c header here
  }
```

I think that will do the trick. Sorry about code formatting above, that functionality does not work on iPhone apparently.